# Loop Categoria no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loop

Alguém sabe como crio um loop para exibir as categorias e quantos posts há em cada uma? Exemplo:

> Categoria-x (15) 
>   Categoria-y (32) 
>   Categoria-z (40)

Onde "categoria"=nome da categoria e 
o número é a quantidade de posts nela.

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei a resposta na [documentação do WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/User:MissLeili/wp_list_categories).
Era só usar a seguinte função:

```
wp_list_categories('show_count = 1');
```

Onde "1" é verdadeiro que indica que é para mostrar a contagem. Padrão "0" (zero).